# MySql process order of where condition

Tags: mysql

Assuming that I have a query as the following

```
 update Object set status=#{statusValue} where attr1=#{par1} or attr2=#{par2};
```

I would like to know the processing order of the condition in the WHERE clause. 
I mean, if attr1=#{par1} result TRUE, the value of par2 is checked or is sufficient the first condition?

Thx

Comment: I suppose every RDBMS does this very basic optimization.  Any reason for such a consideration?

Comment: I think the same, but I wanted a confirmation. I need to be sure because I'm looking at remote to tomcat's log, and I found and error on query like this, but I don't have visibility of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL evaluates boolean expressions left to right, and supports short-circuiting like most programming languages do.

- In an expression `x AND y`, if `x` is false, then `y` is not evaluated.
- In an expression `x OR y`, if `x` is true, then `y` is not evaluated.

You can test this:

```
SET @y := 0;
SELECT true OR (@y := 42);
SELECT @y;
```

Should yield 0, because the right side of the expression was not evaluated.

Comment: Is that true of `WHERE` clauses as well, will the optimiser ever switch the processing order? I'm almost certain it does for `AND` conditions.

Comment: The optimizer will reorder `AND` terms in an expression if it searches a multi-column index. But that's for the index lookup, not for the evaluation of the expression.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation;)

Answer (score 3):

The processing order is undefined, it depends on the row count and column types in your table and any indexes and their cardinality at the time of execution. It also depends on the conditions themselves.

It will only check one condition if the first condition returns `TRUE` however.